# From a Java based application perspective, what’s the purpose of oracle client installed on a server

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, oracleclient

I am trying to understand the purpose of oracle client installed on a VM.

Can a Java application connect to the oracle client using jdbc?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be confusing the Java version included inside the Oracle database (to allow writing procedural code in Java that resides in the database, to implement procedures and functions written in Java, available to users of the database), with a client application, such as Java using JDBC, accessing an Oracle database to retrieve/modify data in the database.

Any Java application running anywhere can connect to an Oracle database instance if you have the correct connection information and network/firewall connectivity, using JDBC.

Comment: My question is different. I’m trying to know the purpose of stand-alone oracle client software that we can install on Linux or windows machines. It contains tools like sqlplus etc. it also contains the tns entry which can be used for client side load balancing etc. is it possible to connect to through client (like a proxy) instead of database server ?

Comment: @las - Put the questions you are really trying to ask into your question.  Use "edit".  (For the record, the "exact purpose" of the Oracle Client install is to provide the tools, libraries, etc that it contains.  The purpose(s) of the tools themselves are largely self-evident.  And: *"is it possible to connect to through client (like a proxy)?"*  No. )

Comment: Can it be used from a Java application in a thick client kind of way? The oracle client software being the thick client.

Comment: You should probably read this: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html